# Delphi constructor how to (inherit a Parent.Parent create) or (call a Parent.Parent.Create)

Tags: delphi, constructor, parent, inherited, inherited-constructors

Hi im trying to call a parent's parent.create effectively bypassing the parent.create

here is an example

```
unit InheritedTest;

interface

  type
  IMyExample = interface
    ['{4B281573-99CC-4B9D-9895-F6BCD0E26F26}']
    procedure Set_MyMessage(const Value: String);
    function Get_MyMessage: String;
    property _MyMessage: String read Get_MyMessage write Set_MyMessage;
  end;

  TMyExample1 = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyExample)
  protected
    fMyMessage: String;
    procedure Set_MyMessage(const Value: String);
    function Get_MyMessage: String;
  published
    property _MyMessage: String read Get_MyMessage write fMyMessage;
    constructor Create();
  end;

  TMyExample2 = class( TMyExample1)
    constructor Create();
  end;

  TMyExample3 = class( TMyExample2)
    constructor Create();
    constructor CreateBypassingTMyExample2Create();
  end;

implementation

{ TMyExample1 }

constructor TMyExample1.Create();
begin
  inherited;
  fMyMessage := 'TMyExample1';
end;

function TMyExample1.Get_MyMessage: String;
begin
  Result := fMyMessage;
end;

procedure TMyExample1.Set_MyMessage(const Value: String);
begin
  fMyMessage := Value;
end;

{ TMyExample2 }

constructor TMyExample2.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  fMyMessage := fMyMessage + ' TMyExample2';
end;

{ TMyExample3 }

constructor TMyExample3.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  fMyMessage := fMyMessage + ' TMyExample3.1';
end;

constructor TMyExample3.CreateBypassingTMyExample2Create;
begin
  //inherited TMyExample1.Create;
  inherited ClassParent.Create;
  fMyMessage := fMyMessage + ' TMyExample3.2';
end;

end.
```

If i create each of these classes and output the message

```
uses InheritedTest;  

...... 

procedure DoCreateTests;
var
  vMyIMyExample1, vMyIMyExample2, vMyIMyExample3_1, vMyIMyExample3_2 : IMyExample;
begin
  vMyIMyExample1 := TMyExample1.Create;
  vMyIMyExample2 := TMyExample2.Create;
  vMyIMyExample3_1 := TMyExample3.Create;
  vMyIMyExample3_2 := TMyExample3.CreateBypassingTMyExample2Create;

  Memo1.Lines.Add( 'vMyIMyExample1._MyMessage = ' + vMyIMyExample1._MyMessage );
  Memo1.Lines.Add( 'vMyIMyExample2._MyMessage = ' + vMyIMyExample2._MyMessage );
  Memo1.Lines.Add( 'vMyIMyExample3_1._MyMessage = ' + vMyIMyExample3_1._MyMessage );
  Memo1.Lines.Add( 'vMyIMyExample3_2._MyMessage = ' + vMyIMyExample3_2._MyMessage );
end;
```

at the moment this is outputting

> vMyIMyExample1._MyMessage = TMyExample1
>   vMyIMyExample2._MyMessage = TMyExample1 TMyExample2
>   vMyIMyExample3_1._MyMessage = TMyExample1 TMyExample2 TMyExample3.1
>   vMyIMyExample3_2._MyMessage =  TMyExample3.2

im trying to get the call TMyExample3.CreateBypassingTMyExample2Create to output

> vMyIMyExample3_2._MyMessage = TMyExample1  TMyExample3.2

what do i need to change in this call to make this work? is it possible to do this without changing or (adding another constructor) to the TMyExample2.create

```
constructor TMyExample3.CreateBypassingTMyExample2Create;
begin
  //inherited TMyExample1.Create;
  inherited ClassParent.Create;
  fMyMessage := fMyMessage + ' TMyExample3.2';
end;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you really trying to accomplish? This sounds like a possible XY problem.

Comment: I'm trying to hijack a 3rd party class and change its constructor but i still want to call its original inherited create..

Comment: sounds more like something that can be accomplished better by patching the vtable than using inheritance.